# Clicking bookmark link in chrome attempts to download file, keyboard ceases to function

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, browser

While using my computer today, chrome randomly decided when I clicked on a bookmark link to attempt to download a file, or if it was a forum page it would download a forum.php page. At the same time, I was unable to type any text to any text areas on the screen. When rebooting, I was unable to type password into the text field.

Eventually rebooting while having the keyboard unplugged solved the issue, but I'm wondering if I may have a hardware issue (it's never done this on this system since it was built, the keyboard is a few years old and a stock logitech USB keyboard), or a possible software issue (using AVG virus scan on windows 7. Has always come back clean.)

So anything I could check to get a definitive answer, or should I be getting the windows disk out and looking to format?

Comment: Does the keyboard only fail when using Google Chrome? For some troubleshooting, try [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) and let me know if you still have the same problem. If so, try disabling plugins in GC Portable by going to `chrome://plugins/` and restarting the browser. If GC Portable works well now with no plugins, then we can go and fix your actual Chrome installation.

Comment: @iglvzx Nope had the same issue with firefox, notepad, etc...